Change ion-button text color when clicked
Having a bit of a fight with my ion-button. I want to customise it for a special case so that:

When it's configured as a link, it is clear.
When the user hovers, there is a coloured underline.
when the user clicks, there is no ripple but the text changes colour.

I have got 1 & 2 to work. And made the ripple go away. But I can't change the text colour on activation!
      // Link
      &.clear {

        // Hover
        &:hover {
          text-decoration: underline;  // Adds an underline
          text-decoration-color: var(--ion-color-secondary, #02c3e8);  // Set the underline color to secondary
          text-underline-offset: 5px;
          text-underline-width: 1.5px;
        }
        --background-hover-opacity: 0.0 !important; // don't want background to show on hover

        // Activated
        &:active {
          --color: var(--ion-color-secondary, #02c3e8) !important;
        }
        --color-activated: var(--ion-color-secondary, #02c3e8) !important; // text color when activated
        --background-activated-opacity: 0.0 !important; // remove background - md ripple still appears
        --ripple-color: var(--app-bg);

Neither of the code approaches above seems to work. I'm sure if we dug into the stencil file, it would somehow tell us why this happens, but as a (not my day job) user, I'd rather it just behaved rationally.

To change the text color when the button is activated, you can use the :active pseudo-class.
// Link
&.clear {
  // Activated
  &:active {
    color: var(--ion-color-secondary, #02c3e8) !important;
  }
}


I agree that your code looks right, but as always with ionic, stuff just doesn't do what you expect sometimes! Tried it, doesn't work...
